# Play Framework PostgreSQL db.default.username defaulting to linux username

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I keep getting errors like this...

```
app[web.1]: Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
app[web.1]:    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)

app[web.1]: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "lcnjgrwbmbffwv"
app[web.1]:    at play.core.StaticApplication.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:55)
app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:408)
app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:410)
app[web.1]:    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
app[web.1]:    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:363)
app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:240)
app[web.1]:    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280)
app[web.1]:    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
app[web.1]:    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
app[web.1]:    ... 18 more
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 255
```

Not just in Heroku, but when I run my Play app with a user whose name is different than the default user name in the database.

My Play Framework "application.conf" is like this...

```
db.default.username="nameOfDatabaseUser"
db.default.password="passOfDatabaseUser"
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://urlofdatabase:5432/name_of_database"
```

Here's the thing. When my terminal user is named "nameOfDatabaseUser", it works. But when my terminal user has a different name, it connects to the database as the name of the current Linux terminal user.

In the above case it appears that Heroku tried to connect as a user *lcnjgrwbmbffwv* and there was no user *lcnjgrwbmbffwv* in the database.

How do I specify the default database username so that it doesn't use my terminal username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct key to specify the user is `db.default.user`, not `db.default.username`.